# Should one use xrange(iterations) or a list of len(iterations) for better performance in a "for loop" evoked 1000000 times?

Tags: python

I have a script that evokes a "for loop" with a set number of iterations (1000) over a million times. I've read the range() vs xrange() threads, and I am aware that I do not want to do something like this.

```
for o in xrange(1000000):
    for i in range(1000): #Definitely do not want
        pass
```

Instead, I wish to create an object that contains 1000 elements and then use that to constantly iterate.

Method 1:

```
iterate=range(1000)
for o in xrange(1000000):
    for i in iterate:    #<---
        pass
```

Method 2:

```
for o in xrange(1000000):
    for i in xrange(1000):    #<----
        pass
```

I was wondering which method would give better performance inside the "for loop." Thank you.

Edit: Sorry. I believe I was unclear. My problem is whether I should make this inner loop I'm evoking use a list already created or use the xrange() for better performance.

Comment: Huh? You want `for i in xrange(1000):`

Comment: @Jochen Yes. I edited my question for better clarity. I was wondering if iterating over an already made list would be faster than iterating using xrange.

Comment: `[x for x in xrange(1000)]` is silly; just use `range(1000)` to initialize `iterate`. Although if you don't need the values, then you might as well use, say, `[None] * 1000`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Noticed my sillyness. Thank you, and thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some local test results:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in repeat(None, 1000): pass', setup='from itertools import repeat', number=100000)
1.94118924332561
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in xrange(1000): pass', number=100000)
2.5231991775491025
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in range(1000): pass', number=100000)
3.9302601308266816
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in r: pass', setup='r = [None] * 1000', number=100000)
2.0900103923822684
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in r: pass', setup='r = range(1000)', number=100000)
2.2248894063351656
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in r: pass', setup='r = xrange(1000)', number=100000)
2.9105822108675823
```

You can't use caching for the `itertools.repeat` one, since that iterator behaves like a generator (you can only "read" the values once, and then they're gone).

Repeating `1` or something similar might be infinitesimally faster because the name `None` no longer has to be looked up, but any such performance benefit is lost in the noise of random variation in test results.

Comment: `itertools` seems to be getting a lot of hype recently, but people still don't seem to be familiar with the *full* tool set it provides. ;) I have no idea why using a cached `xrange` object would be significantly slower than using one created on the fly; that might have just been a blip in testing? Anyway, the `itertools.repeat` approach is clearly superior to everything else in both time and memory usage; I think it's at least as readable, although it's certainly less idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you for the itertools solution. I would've never noticed that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

`xrange()` consumes less memory than `range()`. It is also faster:

```
In [1]: %timeit for i in range(1000): pass

10000 loops, best of 3: 28.8 us per loop

In [2]: %timeit for i in xrange(1000): pass

100000 loops, best of 3: 18.3 us per loop
```

(64-bit Python 2.7.2 on Linux.)

Note that the above uses `xrange()` directly. Your second code snippet (the one with with `iterate`) negates the benefits of using `xrange()` and should be avoided.

Comment: I edited my question for better clarity since the "for loop" I suggested will actually be iterating 1000000 times. I was wondering if Method 1 would give better performance since I constructed the iterating object beforehand and do not generate new objects as in the case of xrange().

Answer (score 2):

[`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) in Python 2.x and [`range`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.3/library/functions.html#range) in 3.x do not build a list in memory and are therefore optimal if you just want to iterate over the values. Building a temporary list with a list expression defeats the purpose though. Instead, you want simply:

```
for i in xrange(1000): # range in Python 3.x
    pass
```

For small numbers like 1000, this is unlikely to be significantly impact performance (the [2.x documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) says the *advantage of `xrange` over `range` is minimal*). Instead,  benchmark your program and find out which part is slow.

Comment: I edited my question for better clarity. I was wondering if it would matter if I made the list before entering the set of "for loops." I thought it might be faster because I wouldn't need to use xrange to generate the same 1000 objects a million times in memory.

Answer (score 0):

xrange will give you better performance due to it not having to allocate the whole resulting list before iterating over it.  This leads to better data cache coherency among other things.

Edit: looking at your example, you are creating the list both times.  I would then say that using range would be more performant in the case that you have given due to it's dedication to creating range lists rather than using a list comprehension through xrange to create the list.

Answer (score 0):

It would perform worth. The benefit of `xrange` is, that it returns an iterable, which means it doesn't create a list of N elements and return it (like `range`):

```
def xrange(n):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        yield i
```

xrange looks similiar to this. So you're LC `iterate = [x for x in xrange(1000)]` equals to `iterate = range(1000)`

Correct code would be:

```
for i in xrange(1000):
    pass
```